# react-google-maps: how to use fitBounds, panBy, panTo, panToBounds public APIs?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

According to the [React Google Maps library](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/master/src/lib/GoogleMap.js#L125-L131), you can call these four methods from the ref object.

What seems weird, is that these methods are supposed to receive two parameters, a map instance and other arguments, like so:

```
fitBounds(map, args) { return map.fitBounds(...args); }
```

However, when calling fitBounds() this way, nothing happens on the map, no bounds are changed and no errors are thrown. This is the way I have structured the component, calling fitBounds in componentDidUpdate:

```
import React from 'react'
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, InfoWindow, Marker, OverlayView } from 'react-google-maps'
import InfoBox from 'react-google-maps/lib/addons/InfoBox'
import map from 'lodash/map'

// Higher-Order Component
const AllocatedPlacesMap = withGoogleMap(props => (
  <GoogleMap
    center={props.center}
    defaultZoom={4}
    options={{ scrollwheel: false, minZoom: 3, maxZoom: 15 }}
    onCenterChanged={props.onCenterChanged}
    ref={props.onMapMounted}>
    {props.markers.map((marker, index) => (
      <Marker
        key={index}
        position={marker.position}
      />
    ))}
  </GoogleMap>
));

class Map extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  getCenter = () => {
    this._bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    this.props.markers.forEach((marker, index) => {
      const position = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.lng);
      this._bounds.extend(position);
    });

    return this._bounds.getCenter();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this._map.fitBounds(this._map, this._bounds);
  }

  handleMapMounted = (map) => {
    this._map = map;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="allocated-places">
        <AllocatedPlacesMap
          containerElement={
            <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
          }
          mapElement={
            <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
          }
          center={this.getCenter()}
          markers={props.markers}
          onMapMounted={this.handleMapMounted}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Map;
```

Any idea of what is the correct way to call fitBounds() in this case? documentation and examples seem to be lacking in this regard.

Comment: fitBounds() no longer requires a map instance as first parameter. This bug was also fixed in v9 of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the function definition `fitBounds(map, args) { return map.fitBounds(...args); }` we can see that the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) is applied on args. That suggests that the `args` should be an array.

So, in your code the second parameter should be of an array type:

```
this._map.fitBounds(this._map, [this._bounds]);
```

You can also include the second element of the array that will be transformed into the second optional parameter `padding` of the Maps JavaScript API [fitBound()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) method.

```
this._map.fitBounds(this._map, [this._bounds, 100]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! but ```this._bounds``` is an object, so the spread operator should work without wrapping it in an array. I tried wrapping it just to test, but nothing happens, no error and the map won't fit the markers.

Comment: If you spread the object you will have iterable properties of this object as parameters of map.fitBounds(). But the first parameter must be entire LatLngBounds or LatLngBoundsLiteral according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map). Can you try to put breakpoint at this function call and check this._bounds object?

Comment: Do you have this issue with initial render? The documentation says: "componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render." https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Answer (score 0):

This is how you call panTo and fitBounds with react map ref

```
this.map.panTo({
  lat:e.latLng.lat(), lng: e.latLng.lng()
})
const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds()
bounds.extend({
  lat:e.latLng.lat(), lng: e.latLng.lng()
})
this.map.fitBounds(bounds)
```